# wordpress API for android app

Tags: json

I'm looking for a plugin that convert everything a user can do on browser into JSON because I want to use this data for an application on android and also I want it to be compatible with woocommerce  plugin. I found two plugins `JSON API` and `WP REST API` but my question is "do they support user login and woocomerce?"

is there any other plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `WP REST API` supports user authentication. With this plugin you can use **OAuth authentication, application passwords, or basic authentication**. Read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/). Here you'll find complete documentation.

For `JSON API` there is a plugin called `JSON API Auth`. [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/) you'll get it. By using it you can implement authentication with `JSON API`.

And yes, as far I know both of them supports `WooCommerce`.