# best way for app users to submit blog post?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm working on an app with andriod studio (java based) and I'm wondering what is the best(your opinion) way for multiple users or random users to submit blog post content to the website. Should they be sending it directly to the mysql db or using http post to website? I am trying to avoid the email plugins as it gets messy and the users have already voiced they hate that style.

I did find this guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android I am trying to use this now but something is telling me I have the wrong idea of how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: Try WP rest API, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236599/wordpress-api-for-android-app